Detecting form input change in Google chat app using Appscript
I have a dialog where users can see tasks assigned to them. Each task displays the task details along with a dropdown to set task status and a text input to set comments. I want to update my task list when the user changes the dropdown or changes the comments. I do have onChangeAction defined for my dropdown
here is what happens: when the user changes the dropdown , it triggers onCardClick and the dialog closes
here is what I want : when the user changes the dropdown, it should be possible to capture the changed value and update the task list without closing the dialog. I've looked through the sample codes on Google developers site but can't find any relevant examples. Please help
  const userEmail = event.message.sender.email;
  const tasks = fetchOpenTasks(userEmail); // Assuming fetchOpenTasks is implemented

  if (tasks.length === 0) {
    return {
      actionResponse: {
        type: "NEW_MESSAGE"
      },
      text: `You have no tasks assigned to you, ${event.message.sender.displayName}.`
    };
  }

  const statusIcons = {
    "Not Started": "", // Red Circle
    "In Progress": "", // Yellow Circle
    "Completed": ""    // Green Circle
  };

  const taskWidgets = tasks.map(task => ({
    widgets: [
      {
        decoratedText: {
          topLabel: task.title,
          text: task.description,  // Combine title and description
          wrapText : true,
          bottomLabel: `Due: ${task.dueDate}`,  // Display due date at the bottom
        }
      },
      {

        columns: 
          {
            columnItems: [
              {
                horizontalSizeStyle : "FILL_MINIMUM_SPACE",
                widgets: [
                  {
                    selectionInput: {
                      name: `status_${task.id}`,
                      label: "Status",
                      type: "DROPDOWN",
                      onChangeAction: { actionMethodName: "onStatusChange",
                        parameters: [{
                          key: "test", value: "test1" }]
                      },
                      items: [
                        { text: `${statusIcons["Not Started"]} Not Started`, value: "Not Started", selected: task.status === "Not Started" },
                        { text: `${statusIcons["In Progress"]} In Progress`, value: "In Progress", selected: task.status === "In Progress" },
                        { text: `${statusIcons["Completed"]} Completed`, value: "Completed", selected: task.status === "Completed" }
                      ],
                      labelPosition: "TOP",
                      buttonStyle: "PRIMARY" // To highlight the dropdown
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                widgets:[
                  {
                    textInput: {
                      name: `comments_${task.id}`,
                      label: "Add Comments",
                      type: "MULTIPLE_LINE",
                      value: task.comments || ""  // Show existing comments or leave empty
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
              
            ]
          }
      }
    ]
  }));

  

  return {
    actionResponse: {
      type: "DIALOG",
      dialogAction: {
        dialog: {
          body: {
            sections: [
              ...taskWidgets // Individual task sections
            ],
            "fixedFooter": {
              "primaryButton": {
                "text": "Save changes",
                "color": {
                  "red": 0,
                  "green": 0.5,
                  "blue": 1,
                  "alpha": 1
                },
                "onClick": {
                  "action": {
                    "function": "updateTasks"
                  }
                }
              },
            }

          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
  
}```


Seems like you shared an incorrect/incomplete code, please share a reproducible code and also some images further explaining the situation would help.

Please also provide context on how your script works by providing further explanation or images for better replication of the issue.
